# Publish Azure Web App from Visual Studio does not update website

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

In Visual Studio 2017:

1. Edited My_Layout.cshtml then right-clicked file > Preview changes to My_Layout.cshtml - change detected
2. Right-clicked file > Publish My_Layout.cshtml
3. Web Publish Activity:
   Preparing to publish files...
   Using ID '8eba-fa723c2cc7fe' for connections to the remote server.
   Using ID '99ee-a03ad6ce124b' for connections to the remote server.
   Updating file (/pj/My_Layout.cshtml).
   Your file(s) have been successfully published.
4. Checked My_Layout.cshtml file content via FTP client - file is updated
5. Refreshed browser - website does not update

The website updates only after an app restart.

What is causing the site to not update after publishing my file and how to fix the issue?

Comment: In your web.config, did you check the [FcnMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.fcnmode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) of httpRuntime attribute

Comment: <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="51200" fcnMode="Disabled" />
what should the value be for fcnMode?

Comment: should be default or single. With disable file change notification is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

try set Fcmode to Default.

- Default:  For each subdirectory, the application creates an object
  that monitors the subdirectory. This is the default behavior.
- Disabled:    File change notification is disabled.
- NotSet:   File change
  notification is not set, so the application creates an object that
  monitors each subdirectory. This is the default behavior.
- Single:   The application creates one object to monitor the main directory and uses
  this object to monitor each subdirectory.